# OpenSSL file encryption trouble

Tags: c, file, encryption, openssl

I am currently developing a SSL encrypted VFS file system for my class and am having some trouble with the file encryption. The example they provided for us required two files, input and output, where the input file text was read, encrypted and written to the output as the encrypted file. However, for the assignment we need to take a single input file and encrypt that file itself not return an encrypted output.

I have written this code below trying to take all the encrypted text and store it in a buffer as i go, then overwrite the input file with the encrypted text saved in the buffer. I am getting a segfault in the code at the last for loop that writes the buffer to the input file. The segfault occurs when count = 4; and z is equal to 3. I assume it is happening because I am storing the data wrong in some way, however I can not seem to pin point the exact problem here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code.

```
#define BLOCKSIZE 1024
#define FAILURE 0
#define SUCCESS 1

extern int do_crypt(FILE* in, int action, char* key_str){
    /* Local Vars */

    /* Buffers */
    unsigned char inbuf[BLOCKSIZE];
    int inlen;
    int z;
    int count = 0;
    /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional cipher block */
    unsigned char outbuf[BLOCKSIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char **storebuf = malloc((BLOCKSIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH)*20);

    int outlen;
    //int writelen;

    /* OpenSSL libcrypto vars */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char key[32];
    unsigned char iv[32];
    int nrounds = 5;

    /* tmp vars */
    int i;

    /* Setup Encryption Key and Cipher Engine if in cipher mode */
    if(action >= 0){
    if(!key_str){
        /* Error */
        fprintf(stderr, "Key_str must not be NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* Build Key from String */
    i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), NULL,
               (unsigned char*)key_str, strlen(key_str), nrounds, key, iv);
    if (i != 32) {
        /* Error */
        fprintf(stderr, "Key size is %d bits - should be 256 bits\n", i*8);
        return 0;
    }
    /* Init Engine */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, action);
    }    

    /* Loop through Input File*/
    for(;;){
    /* Read Block into inbuf */

    inlen = fread(inbuf, sizeof(*inbuf), BLOCKSIZE, in);
    if(inlen <= 0){
        /* EOF -> Break Loop */
        break;
    }

    /* If in encrypt/decrypt mode, perform cipher transform on block */
    if(action >= 0){
        /*set up ctx with passed params */
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen))
        {
            /* Error */
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    /* If in pass-through mode. copy block as is */
    else{
        memcpy(outbuf, inbuf, inlen);
        outlen = inlen;
    }

    storebuf[count] = malloc(outlen*sizeof(*outbuf));
    memcpy(storebuf[count], outbuf, outlen);
    /* Write Block */
    //writelen = fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(*outbuf), outlen, out);//THIS LINE
    if(storebuf[count] == NULL){
        /* Error */
        perror("malloc error");
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    count++;

    }
    count++;
    /* If in cipher mode, handle necessary padding */
    if(action >= 0){
    /* Handle remaining cipher block + padding */
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen))
        {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
        }
    /* Write remaining cipher block + padding*/
    //fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(*inbuf), outlen, out);
    storebuf[count] = malloc(outlen*sizeof(*inbuf));
    memcpy(storebuf[count], outbuf, inlen);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    }
    printf("%d, %s", count, storebuf[count]);

    rewind(in);
    for(z = 0; z < count-1; z++){
        fwrite(storebuf[z], sizeof(*storebuf), strlen((char*)storebuf[z]), in);

    }
    /* Success */
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: A very general comment: normally you don't *write* buffers to an *input file*.

Comment: it is more like a pass through file edited by the function

Answer (score 1):

The ecnrypted data you get are in binary form and are not a NULL-terminated string. You cannot use strlen(), you need to use the value stored in outlen.